# Is there a R plot_ly subplot function that sets the text size of subplot titles?

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to change the size of subplot title text using plot_ly subplot.

I am currently using the following code:

```
subplot(unemployed, employed, not_in_labor_force, 
        nrows = 3,
        titleY = TRUE, titleX = TRUE, shareX = TRUE) %>%
        layout(title = "Employment, Unemployment, and Not in Labor Force Shares by Race",
               yaxis = list(zerolinewidth = 2, 
                            zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
                            titlefont = list(size = 8)))
```

[Image of the Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y3kA.png)

As you can see, only the first subplot had it's title respond to the size = 8 function.

How can I change the other titles?

I tried setting the title size in each of the plot_ly objects, I also tried to use titlefont2 = ... both threw errors rather than changing the subplot output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As your code isn't reproducible I'm using [this](https://plotly.com/r/subplots/#stacked-subplots) example.

You can set the y-axis font size for each plot as follows:

```
# Warning messages:
#   1: The titlefont attribute is deprecated. Use title = list(font = ...) instead.

library(plotly) 
fig1 <- plot_ly(x = c(3, 4, 5), y = c(1000, 1100, 1200), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers') |> layout(yaxis = list(title = list(text = 'Title A', font = list(size = 8)))) 
fig2 <- plot_ly(x = c(2, 3, 4), y = c(100, 110, 120), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers') |> layout(yaxis = list(title = list(text = 'Title B', font = list(size = 8)))) 
fig3 <- plot_ly(x = c(0, 1, 2), y = c(10, 11, 12), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers') |> layout(yaxis = list(title = list(text = 'Title C', font = list(size = 8)))) 
fig <- subplot(fig1, fig2, fig3, nrows = 3, titleY = TRUE, titleX = TRUE, shareX = TRUE, which_layout = "merge") %>% 
  layout(title = list(text = "Stacked Subplots"),
         plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6', 
         xaxis = list( 
           zerolinecolor = '#ffff', 
           zerolinewidth = 2, 
           gridcolor = 'ffff'), 
         yaxis = list( 
           zerolinecolor = '#ffff', 
           zerolinewidth = 2, 
           gridcolor = 'ffff')) 
fig
```

[image: result]